# Why can't I target the complement of my goal in Optimizely?

Tags: web, ab-testing, optimizely

Optimizely's [Sample Size calculator](https://www.optimizely.com/resources/sample-size-calculator/) shows, that a higher baseline conversion rate leads to a smaller required sample size for an A/B-test. So, instead of maximizing my conversion goal, I'd like to minimize the opposite, i.e. *not* reaching the goal.
For every goal with a conversion rate less than 50%, its complement would be higher than 50% and would thus require a smaller sample size if targeted.

An example: instead of measuring all users that visit `payment-success.html`, I'd rather measure all users that *don't* visit it, and try minimizing that. Which would usually require a lot smaller sample size if my reasoning is correct!

Optimizely only lets me target pageviews as goals, not *not*-pageviewing.
I realize I'm probably missing or misunderstanding something important here, but if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistically there's nothing wrong with your approach, but unfortunately it won't have the desired effect of lowering the duration.

While you'll reduce the margin of error, you'll proportionately decrease the lift, causing you to take the same amount of time to reach confidence.

Since the lift is calculated as a percentage of the baseline conversion rate, the same change in conversion rate of a larger baseline will produce a smaller lift.

Say your real conversion rate is 10% and the test winds up increasing it to 12%. The inverse conversion rate would be 90% which gets lowered to 88%. In both cases it's a change of 2%, but 2% is a much greater change to 10% (it's a 20% lift) than it is to 90% (only a -2.22% lift).

*Practically*, you run a much larger risk of incorrectly bucketing people into the goal with the inverse. You know that someone who hits the success page should be counted toward the goal. I'm pretty sure what you're suggesting would cause *every pageview* that wasn't on the success page after the user saw the experiment to count as a goal.

Say you're testing the home page. Person A and B both land on the home page and view the experiment.

- Person A visits 1 other pages and leaves
- Person B visits 1 other pages and buys something

If your goal was setup on the success page, only person B would trigger the goal. If the goal was setup on all other pages, both people would trigger the goal. That's obviously not the inverse.

In fact, if there are any pages necessary to reach the success page after the user first sees the experiment (so unless you're testing the final step of checkout), *everyone* will trigger the inverse pageview goal (whether they hit the success page or not).

Optimizely pageview goals aren't just for pages included in the URL Targeting of your experiment. They're counted for anyone who's seen the experiment and at any point afterward hit that page.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer whether this is **possible** (not addressing whether your setup will result in the same outcome), you're right that Optimizely pageview goal doesn't allow for *not*, but you can probably use the Regex match type to achieve what you want (see 'URL Match Type' in point 3 [here](https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/200090069#setup)). In this case it would look like this, taken from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) (which also explains the complexity involved with *not* matching in Regex, suggesting why Optimizely hasn't built *not* pageviews into the product).

`^((?!payment-success\.html).)*$`

Hopefully that helps you get to where you want.

Comment: The problem with this is that it would match when any page is viewed other than payment-success. However, It needs to track _all_ page views other than payment-success during a session… Otherwise, it wouldn't be the complement of visiting that page.